# How can I tell if my ansible.cfg is working?

Tags: ansible

I have an `ansible.cfg` file. Ansible isn't behaving as expected for me, but I don't know if that's because my configuration isn't working or because my `ansible.cfg` file isn't even getting picked up at all.

How can I verify whether my `ansible.cfg` is working?

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***"I don't know if my configuration isn't working or my ansible.cfg file isn't even getting picked up at all."***

A: Run the command

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump --only-changed
```

This will *`"Only show configurations that have changed from the default"`* and will also reveal the source of the change either it's a configuration file or an environment variable.

For details see [Configuration settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#configuration-settings).